# Keyframes animation box is not consistent around all sides

Tags: css

I am making a custom 404 error page which consists of an animated box around the verbiage.  The problem I'm running into is that the box is not animating consistently.  Specifically, the left & bottom sides are not matching the right & top sides.

Here is my code snippet:

```css
* {
  transition: all 0.6s;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #9e9e9e;
  margin: 0;
}

#main {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.fof {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.fof h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 12px;
  animation: type .5s alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes type {
  from {
    box-shadow: inset -3px 5px 5px 5px #9e9e9e;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 0px transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="fof">
    <h1>404<br>Not Found</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see from the code above - the left & bottom sides' animation should match the right & top sides to form a consistent box.

I have tried to alter this piece of code:

```css
@keyframes type {
  from {
    box-shadow: inset -3px 5px 5px 5px #9e9e9e;
  }
  to {
    box-shadow: inset -3px 0px 0px transparent;
  }
}
```

...by changing the selectors and it either does nothing or removes the box entirely.  I'm just not sure if I'm attempting this correctly.

Can someone provide some guidance on how to change the animation box to be consistent on all sides?  Specifically, to match the right & top sides.  Thank you.

Comment: your shadow is shifted, you can change coordinates to 0 0 to centre the shadow like this: inset 0px 0px 5px 5px #9e9e9e